# Función que reciba la dirección donde va a almacenar el resultado de la selección

Tags: c

Estoy intentando mandar un puntero a una función por parámetros para que este mismo sea manipulado en la función y almacene el dato que le indico pero no me funciona, al imprimir ambos punteros me dan direcciones diferentes y obviamente no tienen el mismo dato ¿Cómo hago para mandar el puntero y que se manipule el mismo en la función?

Lenguaje C

```
#include <stdio.h>


void MENU(char *PSEL);

//ESTA FUNCIÓN RECIBE LA DIRECCIÓN DONDE VA A ALMACENAR EL RESULTADO DE LA SELECCIÓN
void MENU(char *PSEL){ //RECIBO EL PUNTERO
    char dato[1];
    printf("\n\t [S] SUMA \n\t [R] RESTA \n\t [M] MULTIPLICACION \n\t [D] DIVISION \nIngresa tu opcion: ");
    scanf("%c", &dato); //LEE EL DATO

    *PSEL=dato;  //ASIGNA EL DATO AL PUNTERO
    printf("\nDireccion en PSEL: %p%s%c", &PSEL, " \nDato almacenado: ", *PSEL); //IMPRESIÓN DE DATOS DE PUNTERO
}



int main(){
    char seleccion[1]; //PUNTERO A MANDAR
    MENU(&seleccion); //LLAMADA A FUNCIÓN MANDANDO PUNTERO

    printf("\n\nDireccion en Seleccion: %p%s%c", &seleccion, " \nEl dato almacenado es: ", seleccion); //IMPRESIÓN DE DATOS DE PUNTERO
    printf("\n\n\n\nTermine");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `seleccion` tiene que ser de tipo `int` en vez de `int*`. Y por favor no pegues código como imagen, pues puede ser dificil o imposible de leer para algunas personas. Mejor copia el código y pégalo en la pregunta, encerrado entre dos líneas con triple back-tick ```

Comment: Hola, una disculpa, es la primera vez que uso esta plataforma, apenas me voy adaptando.

Comment: Ya quité el ** Int* ** y dejé el int sólo, me sigue fallando, lanza punteros diferentes

Comment: Pero en la llamada a MENU tienes que seguir pasando `&seleccion` como tenías originalmente. Quieres pasar la dirección *de un entero*, pero antes estabas pasando la dirección de un puntero. Y dentro de la función, para modificar el valor al que apunta, debes hacer `*PSEL = dato` en lugar de `PSEL=&dato`. Tienes un lío con lo que significan el `*` y el `&`. Si quieres puedo explicarlo en una respuesta

Comment: Mira, en realidad estaba utilizando valores **int** para poder facilitar el trabajo de punteros ya que tengo que realizarlo en realidad con **char**, lo que tengo que realizar es lo siguiente.                                                                                          **void Menu(char *PSEL);** Esta función recibe la dirección donde va a dejar el resultado de la selección dentro del menú.                                                         Entonces estoy creando una puntero de tipo **char** llamado ***seleccion** el cuál irá a la función

Comment: El objetivo es que una vez seleccionada una opción en el menu, ese mismo valor poderlo manipular en el método main

Comment: Modifiqué el código para ver si es más objetivo mi punto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `MENU` espera un puntero de tipo entero:

```
void MENU(int *PSEL);
//        ~~~~~ puntero de tipo int
```

Y eso es justamente lo que deberías pasarle. Sin embargo tu le estás pasando un entero:

```
int seleccion; //PUNTERO A MANDAR
MENU(seleccion); //LLAMADA A FUNCIÓN MANDANDO PUNTERO
```

Un entero es una variable que almacena números enteros (sin decimales). Un puntero es una variable que almacena direcciones de memoria ... no son lo mismo.

La solución más sencilla aquí sería pasarle a `MENU` la dirección de memoria de `seleccion`:

```
MENU(&seleccion);
```

El operador `&` te permite obtener la dirección de memoria de una variable.

Si ahora nos vamos a la función `MENU`, vemos otro problema y es que la función estaría referenciando una variable local:

```
void MENU(int *PSEL){ //RECIBO EL PUNTERO
    int dato;   // variable local
    PSEL=&dato; // referenciamos la variable local
}
```

Las variables locales dejan de existir cuando el programa abandona su ámbito. Cuando decimos que dejan de existir es simplemente que la variable ya no puede ser usada, su memoria se ha liberado y puede ser utilizada libremente por otras variables para almacenar sus propios valores.

Aquí no necesitas usar una variable local. La función `MENU` puede usar directamente `PSEL` en lugar de `dato`:

```
void MENU(int *PSEL){ //RECIBO EL PUNTERO
    printf("\n\t [S] SUMA \n\t [R] RESTA \n\t [M] MULTIPLICACION \n\t [D] DIVISION \nIngresa tu opcion: ");
    scanf("%d", PSEL); //LEE EL DATO

    printf("entro");
    printf("\nDireccion en PSEL: %p %d", &PSEL, *PSEL); //IMPRESIÓN DE DATOS DE PUNTERO
}
```

El código ahora queda un poco más limpio y es más seguro, pues no expones direcciones de memoria no válidas.

> Corregí el código y lo adapté a todo lo que mencionas, de igual manera me sigue arrojando valores distintos, dirección de memoria distinta y valor almacenado distinto.

Eso sucede porque el `printf` de `MENU` está mal:

```
printf("\nDireccion en PSEL: %p%s%c", &PSEL, " \nDato almacenado: ", *PSEL);
//                                    ~~~~~
```

El atributo `%p` recupera la dirección de memoria almacenada en un puntero. Sin embargo, como parámetro le estás pasando `&PSEL`, es decir, la dirección de memoria de PSEL. El resultado es que esa línea te está mostrando la dirección de memoria propia de `PSEL`, no la dirección de memoria a la que apunta:

```
0x12345     0x88432
PSEL     -> seleccion
```

Es decir, cada variable que declaras en el programa ocupa su propia posición de memoria. Es en ese *espacio* donde la variable almacena información. Un puntero es, por tanto, una variable que almacena direcciones de memoria y esas direcciones se deben almacenar en algún sitio.

Para obtener la dirección de memoria apuntada por `PSEL` tienes que quitar el `&`:

```
printf("\nDireccion en PSEL: %p%s%c", PSEL, " \nDato almacenado: ", *PSEL);
```

Aunque también podrías aprovechar para simplificar un poco ese `printf`:

```
printf("\nDireccion en PSEL: %p\nDato almacenado: %c", PSEL, *PSEL);
```

Comment: Hola, una mega disculpa, estoy tratando de incorporar lo que me mencionas conforme lo voy entendiendo ya que cambié todos los **int** por **char** que es el tipo de dato que debo manejar

Comment: Corregí el código y lo adapté a todo lo que mencionas, de igual manera me sigue arrojando valores distintos, dirección de memoria distinta y valor almacenado distinto.

Comment: @Jonathan he actualizado la respuesta, échale un ojo

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a *abulafia* y a *eferion*, ambos me aportaron bastante para este problema que traía de horas.

El código quedó de la siguiente forma:

```
void MENU(char *PSEL){
    printf("\n\t [S] SUMA \n\t [R] RESTA \n\t [M] MULTIPLICACION \n\t [D] DIVISION \nIngresa tu opcion: ");
    scanf("%c", PSEL);
    printf("\nDireccion de PSEL: %p %s %c", PSEL," \nDato almacenado: ",*PSEL);
}
```

```
int main(){
    char seleccion;
    MENU(&seleccion);
    printf("\n\nDireccion de Seleccion: %p %s %c", &seleccion, " \nDato almacenado: ", seleccion);
    printf("\n\n\n\nTermine");
    return(0);
}
```

**Ya está funcionando perfectamente**

[image: Compilación exitosa]

Comment: No hay de qué, pero de nuevo has usado la zona de respuestas para poner algo que no es exactamente una respuesta. Los agradecimientos deben ir en comentarios. Y el mejor agradecimiento de todas formas es votar positivamente la respuesta y aceptar la que mejor resuelva la consulta.

Comment: Por cierto, que he visto que habías posteado otra pregunta similar, y estaba respondiéndola cuando la borraste. Así que para no perder la respuesta que ya tenía escrita la he añadido a esta pregunta, aunque ya está resuelta.

Comment: En pocas palabras: **Este sitio no es un foro**. Cada pregunta tiene su propia página. **Las respuestas deben responder directamente a la pregunta**, no deben ser una mera réplica ni usarse para discusión. Justamente la zona de comentarios está para pedir o dar información, o hablar en relación a la pregunta/respuesta. Para conversaciones extensas existe el [chat].

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios errores de concepto en tu código:

1. El array que has declarado como `char *seleccion[1];` es un array de punteros (eso es lo que significa el `*` delante del nombre de la variable) y no un puntero a un array, que se habría declarado así: `char (*seleccion)[1];`
2. En cualquier caso no necesitas aqui un puntero a array (ni el array de punteros que tenías), sino un simple array de caracteres. Es más, ya que sólo usas 1 caracter del array, la declaración podría ser de un solo char: `char seleccion;`
3. Cuando llamas a la función tienes que pasar la dirección de la variable que pretendes que la función modifique. Eso lo tienes bien, pues se hace poniendo un `&` delante del nombre de la variable: `MENU(&seleccion);`
4. Pero cuando estás dentro de la función la variable que tienes `PSEL` es otra variable diferente, que existe solo dentro de la función. Al ser una variable diferente, está en un lugar de la memoria diferente. Es por eso que `&PSEL` muestra diferente dirección que `&seleccion`. Son variables distintas.
5. Lo que ocurre es que *el valor* de `PSEL` es la dirección de `&seleccion`. Es decir, durante la llamada es como si en algún punto se hubiera hecho `PSEL=&seleccion`. Por tanto si quieres ver *a dónde apunta `PSEL`* tienes que imprimir el valor de `PSEL` y no el de `&PSEL` (esto no te da a dónde apunta, sino dónde está almacenada la propia `PSEL`)
6. Finalmente, y para completar la explicación, si quieres ver *el dato al que apunta `PSEL`* tendrías que usar el asterisco. Esto se denomina *desreferenciar el puntero*. Es decir, la sintaxis `*PSEL`. Eso te da el `char` que está almacenado en la dirección apuntada por `PSEL` y ya que `PSEL` está apuntando a la dirección `&seleccion`, eso te daría el carácter almacenado en la variable `seleccion`. Usando esta sintaxis también puedes modificar ese dato, mediante `*PSEL='x'` por ejemplo, lo que metería una `'x'` en la dirección apuntada, modificando por tanto el valor de `seleccion`

Es decir, el código podría quedar así:

```
void MENU(char *PSEL){
    printf("\n\t [S] SUMA \n\t [R] RESTA \n\t [M] MULTIPLICACION \n\t [D] DIVISION \nIngresa tu opcion: ");
    scanf("%c", PSEL);
    printf("\nDireccion de PSEL: %p %s %c", PSEL," \nDato almacenado: ",*PSEL);
}

int main(){
    char seleccion;
    MENU(&seleccion);
    printf("\n\nDireccion de Seleccion: %p %s %c", &seleccion, " \nDato almacenado: ", seleccion);
    printf("\n\n\n\nTermine");
    return(0);
}
```

Un último detalle es que dentro de `MENU()` usamos `scanf()` para leer la respuesta del usuario. `scanf()` espera que le pases la dirección de memoria donde ha de dejar el resultado. Como ves le pasamos `PSEL` porque es esa variable la que *contiene* la dirección en la que queremos el resultado. Sería incorrecto poner `&PSEL` porque entonces el resultado quedaría en la variable `PSEL` y no en la dirección apuntada por `PSEL`.

Comment: Hola Abufalia, la parte anterior quedó pero ahora tengo otro problema, no sé si te pueda pasar mi código para que lo revises, tengo datos almacenados en 2 variables pero al momento de asignarlos al apuntador  ´´´*PR = PA*PB;´´´ me da como multiplicación cero ¿sabes por qué? las variables si tienen sus datos

Comment: La suma y resta si me las da, la multiplicación y división no y es básicamente el mismo método sólo cambian los operadores